# How to configure Ant in netbeans 6.9 for my zend framework project

Tags: zend-framework, netbeans, ant, netbeans-6.9

I switched to net-beans 6.9.1 to develop my php zend framework projects. Now I want it to work with ANT. I have already an build directory with an build.xml.
Can someone tell me how to configure and run my ant scripts from within netbeans?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Tools and Plugins, and install the Ant plugin under the "Java SE" category. You should also install the Ant 1.8.1 documentation plugin.

Then you can just right-click on your build.xml file, and you should be able to run targets in Ant.